# How do I compare one input value to another input value in laravel controller?

Tags: laravel

How do I compare one input value to another input value in laravel controller?

```
$data = $this->validate($request, [
 'suppler_id' => 'required',
 'date'  => 'required',
 'item_name' => 'required', 
 'item_quantity' => 'required',
 'item_rate' => 'required',
 'total' => 'required',
 'pay' => 'required_with:total|integer|lte:total|',

]);
```

Here I want to compare between total field and pay field to ensure that total is bigger than pay.

Answer (score 2):

```
//...
'input1'=> 'lt:input2',
//...
```

> Do mind that input1 and input2 must be of the same type. See:
>   https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-lt